# How safe is the single engine taxi out for twin engine aircraft?

Tags: engine, taxiing

Fuel conservation programs are leading to single engine taxi out, asking the crew to start the other engine near or on the position 2, where the ground crew cannot monitor the engine's status outside the aircraft.
How safe is this procedure? One example is the jet pipe fire during the start up.

Comment: Are you assuming that mechanics always monitor engines during startup closer to the gate? Even closer to the runway, other aircraft or ATC should still be paying attention. They tend to notice things like engines on fire.

Comment: Are they responsible for that? I mean, from a distance, it could seem to be, or even to late for an instant action. couldn't it?

Comment: Well ATC is responsible for keeping everyone moving safely, and have been faulted when not paying enough attention, so I would say they are somewhat responsible in this role.

Comment: I agree partially. For sure they are responsible for this and many other actions, and they would inform the crew a little bit late, while the mechanicas are responsible for this, during the start up procedures.

Comment: Mechanics are not responsible for startups, in fact they are very rarely present for engine starts, so regardless of it being at the gate, or the ramp, or the taxiway, or the runway, the responsibility lies with the pilots in the aircraft and people observing on the ground to report things out of the ordinary.

Comment: I disagree with your post, the mechanics (ramp personnel) assist the pilot while they are pushing back, and starting the engines as well.

Comment: FWIW, before my retirement in 1999, mechanics were rarely present for engine starts, and to refer to a mechanic as a ramp person would have been highly insulting to a mechanic. Ramp personnel, at least back then, were not licensed, and were paid far less than mechanics, who, of course, had to have A&E licenses. Actually, as I remember, more often than not, we referred to ramp personnel as ramp rats.

Comment: As I am neither a pilot nor airport agent, I am allowed to make mistakes, and to me, and most of the passengers, the ground crew who is connected to the aircraft by the radio system would be mechanics, however, I'd never call them as "rats", to us they are as essential as pilots.

Comment: they aren't essential at all. A pilot (or a properly trained mechanic) can taxi a plane without a ramp rat, but a ramp rat can't taxi a plane without a pilot. those orange flashlights the ramp rats use don't actually move the aircraft :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of mechanics watching civil aircraft start up. They usually have far better things to do. Aircrew are responsible for the aircraft at this point.

The question on a twin is about directional control not safety. How easy is it to taxi on one engine without losing control or stressing the aircraft or tyres in any way? I think this probably depends on the aircraft, some will be easier than others. Also if its a piston twin, you don't want to wait for the other engine to warm up when you are ready for departure. Some four engined aircraft might taxi on two engines - one either side but I've never heard of twins doing this routinely.

Comment: Fuel conservation program requires, for example, LATAM Airlines, the A320/21s perform the taxi in and out, with only the engine number 2 running.

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking more of light twins with piston engines.

Comment: I see saab 2000s do this quite often